# How to calculate the determinant of this matrix

Tags: determinant

I need to calculate the determinant of this matrix:

[image]

How can I do it wisely?

Comment: you can actually compute all the eigenvalues of this matrix, and the determinant is the product

Comment: I haven`t yet learned about eigenvalues , so I would like to think of another way

Comment: there's an easy way to reduce the matrix to a triangular form. from there it's easy to compute the determinant